# Flutter navigation rail focus not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making a cross-platform app to watch anime using Flutter and go router. So in order for it to work on android tv it needs dpad selection or focus system. So according to the screen size, it shows the bottom nav bar or navigation rail. I implemented the focus mechanism but it doesn't work on the navigation rail, bottom nav bar, and app bar buttons. I actually extended the navigation rail destination and bottom nav bar item. please help me. here is the code.

```
`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScaffoldWithBottomNavBarTabItem extends BottomNavigationBarItem {

final String initialLocation;

const ScaffoldWithBottomNavBarTabItem(

{required this.initialLocation, required Widget icon, String? label})

: super(icon: icon, label: label);

}

class ScaffoldWithSideNavBarTabItem extends NavigationRailDestination {

final String initialLocation;

const ScaffoldWithSideNavBarTabItem(

{required this.initialLocation, required Widget icon, required Widget selectedIcon, required Widget label})

: super(icon: icon, selectedIcon: selectedIcon, label: label);

}`

this is the extensions

`const side_nav_bar_tabs = [

ScaffoldWithSideNavBarTabItem(

initialLocation: '/',

icon: Icon(Icons.home),

selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.home),

label: Text('Home'),

),

ScaffoldWithSideNavBarTabItem(

initialLocation: '/forum',

icon: Icon(Icons.forum),

selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.forum),

label: Text('Forum'),

),

ScaffoldWithSideNavBarTabItem(

initialLocation: '/browse',

icon: Icon(Icons.search),

selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.search),

label: Text('Browse'),

),

ScaffoldWithSideNavBarTabItem(

initialLocation: '/library',

icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark),

selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.bookmark),

label: Text('Library'),

),

ScaffoldWithSideNavBarTabItem(

initialLocation: '/account',

icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),

selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),

label: Text('Account'),

),

];`

tabs/destinations

`int currentIndex(BuildContext context, List tabs) {

String loc = GoRouterState.of(context).location;

int index = tabs.indexWhere((t) => t.initialLocation.startsWith(loc));

if (index < 0) {

if (loc.startsWith('/user')) {

return tabs.indexWhere((t) => t.initialLocation.endsWith('/user'));

} else if (loc.startsWith('/anime')) {

return tabs.indexWhere((t) => t.initialLocation.endsWith('/browse'));

} else if (loc.startsWith('/browse')) {

return tabs.indexWhere((t) => t.initialLocation.endsWith('/browse'));

} else if (loc.startsWith('/forum')) {

return tabs.indexWhere((t) => t.initialLocation.endsWith('/forum'));

} else {

return 0;

}

} else {

return index;

}

}

void onItemTapped(BuildContext context, List tabs, int tabIndex) {

if (tabIndex != currentIndex) {

context.go(tabs[tabIndex].initialLocation);

}

}

class LeftIntent extends Intent {}

class RightIntent extends Intent {}

class UpIntent extends Intent {}

class DownIntent extends Intent {}

class ActionIntent extends Intent {}

class ScaffoldWithSideNavbar extends StatelessWidget {

final Widget child;

const ScaffoldWithSideNavbar({super.key, required this.child});

@override

Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Scaffold(

appBar: AppBar(

title: const Text('Sanji.to'),

actions: [

Focus(

child: IconButton(

icon: Icon(Icons.search),

onPressed: () => context.goNamed('browse'),

),

),

]

),

body: Shortcuts(

shortcuts: <LogicalKeySet, Intent>{

LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.select): const ActivateIntent(),

LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowUp): UpIntent(),

LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowDown): DownIntent(),

LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowLeft): LeftIntent(),

LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowRight): RightIntent(),

},

child: Row(

children: [

NavigationRail(

destinations: side_nav_bar_tabs,

selectedIndex: currentIndex(context, side_nav_bar_tabs),

onDestinationSelected: (int index) => onItemTapped(context, side_nav_bar_tabs, index),

groupAlignment: 0.0,

labelType: NavigationRailLabelType.none,

selectedIconTheme: Themes.navigator_icon_selected,

unselectedIconTheme: Themes.navigator_icon_unselected,

/*

trailing: InkWell(

onTap: () => context.goNamed("forum"),

child: Icon(Icons.account_circle),

),*/

),

Expanded(

child: child,

)

],

),

),

);

}

}`

the scaffold

`final _router = GoRouter(

errorBuilder: (context, state) => PageNotFound(),

initialLocation: '/',

routes: <RouteBase>[

ShellRoute(

builder: (context, state, child) {

return return_screen(context, child);

},

routes: <RouteBase>[

GoRoute(

name: 'home',

path: '/',

builder: (context, state) => HomePage(),

),

GoRoute(

name: 'forum',

path: '/forum',

builder: (context, state) => CommunityPage(),

),

GoRoute(

name: 'create-post',

path: '/forum/create-post',

redirect: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {

if (isBoxNULL('token', 'token')) {

return null;

} else {

return '/account/login';

}

},

builder: (context, state) => CreatePostPage(),

),

GoRoute(

name: 'post',

path: '/forum/post/:postId',

builder: (context, state) => PostPage(postID: state.params['postId']!),

),

GoRoute(

name: 'browse',

path: '/browse',

builder: (context, state) => BrowsePage(),

),

GoRoute(

name: 'library',

path: '/library',

builder: (context, state) => LibraryPage(),

),

GoRoute(

name: 'account',

path: '/account',

redirect: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {

if (isBoxNULL('token', 'token')) {

return null;

} else {

return '/account/login';

}

},

builder: (context, state) => AccountPage(),

),

GoRoute(

name: 'login',

path: '/account/login',

builder: (context, state) => LoginPage(),

),

GoRoute(

name: 'register',

path: '/account/register',

builder: (context, state) => RegisterPage(),

),

GoRoute(

name: 'search',

path: '/browse/anime/search',

builder: (context, state) => SearchPage(filter: state.queryParams['filter']!),

),

GoRoute(

name: 'animedetails',

path: '/anime/:animeId',

builder: (context, state) => AnimePage(id: state.params['animeId']!),

),

GoRoute(

name: 'animestream',

path: '/anime/:animeId/:animeEp',

builder: (context, state) => AnimeStreamPage(id: state.params['animeId']!, ep: state.params['animeEp']!),

),

],

),

],

);`

router on main.dart
```

the get_screen() just returns the scaffold based on the screen width

Spend many time to debug. Please help

I tried many things but didnt work